# For software versioning is 1.2.3 newer or older than 1.2.17?

Tags: architecture, versioning, archive, software-distribution, api-versioning

I was stumped when I was trying to upgrade the jar files in my pom.xml

For *software versioning* is 1.2.3 newer or older than 1.2.17?

I understand that in Maths, 0.3 is greater than 0.17 and is more recent

but if the '.' has nothing to do with decimals and is just a placeholder

then 3 is less than 17 and is older.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Incrementing_sequences)

> Incrementing sequences There are two schools of thought regarding how
>   numeric version numbers are incremented. Most free and open-source
>   software packages, including MediaWiki, treat versions as a series of
>   individual numbers, separated by periods, with a progression such as
>   1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, and so on.
>
> On the other hand, some software packages identify releases by decimal
>   numbers: 1.7, 1.8, 1.81, 1.82, 1.9, etc. Decimal versions were common
>   in the 1980s, for example with NetWare, DOS, and Microsoft Windows,
>   but even in the 2000s have been for example used by Opera[7] and
>   Movable Type.[8] In the decimal scheme, 1.81 is the minor version
>   following 1.8, while maintenance releases (i.e. bug fixes only) may be
>   denoted with an alphabetic suffix, such as 1.81a or 1.81b.

Answer (score 1):

For software, `1.2.3` is older than `1.2.17`. Each number after the `.` is compared with the number at the corresponding position. Since `17 > 3`, therefore `1.2.17` is newer than `1.2.3` or in other words, `1.2.3` is older than `1.2.17`. I've never seen an example in the last ten years where `1.2.3` is considered as a newer version than `1.2.17`.

Comment: ok, so they are not really decimals. I wonder how it is in the Dewey Decimal System that (book) libraries use.

Comment: @likejudo - That's correct. Here `.` is used just as a separator.

Comment: I don't know. Software programs are more akin to this system of classification.  see my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

In  the Dewey Decimal System which libraries use, 1.2.3 would be newer than 1.2.17.

From this [article](http://sixthformstudyskills.ncl.ac.uk/libraries/overview-the-dewey-decimal-system/), .805 is *less* (older) than .81

> The Dewey Decimal system is a classification system used by libraries
>   to arrange books via subject. ... After the three digits there is a
>   decimal point and numbers after the decimal point show the sub-section
>   of the subject area. Again they are shelved in numerical order e.g.
>   **945.805 is shelved before 945.81**.